# Composer doesn't loads files

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am facing a problem with php composer. After adding a dependency on composer.json I run `composer install` and composer `dump-autoload` it installed new dependency but didn't create `autoload_files.php` at all.

I am developing on Laravel 5.6
Composer current version 1.6.5

Structure of Composer.json

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers/someHelper.php",
        "app/helpers/dataTypes.php",
        ...
    ]
},
  ...
}
```

I thought there might be some update in composer that can cause the issue but I couldn't find such a thing on the investigation, if someone can help me about that it will be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't realize that composer.json got messed up, it was the night when I asked the question, but now(morning I saw that composer.json got mixed somehow. Autoload key had redefined in autoload key, that is why the issue caused.